# Unset all properties of a Backbone.js model that start with the same substring

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, underscore.js

I would like to unset all properties of a Backbone.js model that start with the same substring like:

```
logo_id
logo_width
logo_height
```

I would like to do something like:

```
model.unsetAllStartsWith('logo');
```

The code would be something like:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model, {
    unsetAllStartsWith : function(str){
        // something with this.toJSON() ?
    }
});
```

I get confused with models and toJSON.  Also, is that the correct way to extend the Backbone model class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone.Model has an extend method built in, so you can do this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    unsetAllStartsWith: function(str){
       // get clone of attributes to iterate over
       var attrs = _.clone(this.attributes);
       _.each(attrs, function(val, key){
              if(key.indexOf(str) == 0){
                  this.unset(key);
              }
           }, this);
    }
});

var model = new MyModel({logo_width: 100, logo_height: 200});
model.unsetAllStartsWith('logo');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.

```
 unsetAllStartsWith : function(str){
        var $this = this
        var properties = Object.keys($this.toJSON());
        _.each(properties, function(property) {
            var regex = new RegExp('^'+ str, 'gi')
            if(property.match(regex))
               $this.unset(property)        
        }

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different take on adding the method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctasims/q8paf/)):

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.unsetAllStartsWith = function(prefix) {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.attributes, function(attrVal, attrName) {
      if (attrName.slice(0,prefix.length) === prefix) {
          that.unset(attrName);
      }
  })
};
```

Use like so:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'foo_first': 'bar',
        'foo_second': 'bar2',
        'different': 'bar3'
    }
});

var testModel = new MyModel();
testModel.unsetAllStartsWith('foo');
```